# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте! Не могу понять, нужны ли здесь запятые?

> Антонина Ивановна **когда нужно** поругает, а когда и похвалит.

Comment: @Оксана Владимировна, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что запятые не нужны: Антонина Ивановна когда нужно поругает, а когда и похвалит.

Оборот на основе придаточного может выступать в роли одного слова, что видно из следующих примеров.

Обособленное обстоятельство: Он изводил себя и других репетициями, разучивал партии, будучи приглядчивым капельмейстером, а когда нужно ― и квартирмейстером.Персонажи будут вовремя входить и выходить, а когда нужно, танцевать вокруг нас. Он умел, когда нужно, подчиниться обстоятельствам,

Необособленное обстоятельство: Баннер показывается не там и не когда нужно. Это особенно эффективно для поддержания хорошей формы, а не когда нужно резко сбросить 25 килограмм.
Главное не торопить, сама все сделает когда нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые нужны.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

XXIX. ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ, НЕ ЯВЛЯЮЩИХСЯ ПРИДАТОЧНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯМИ

§114. Цельные по смыслу выражения

Особенно вот этот пример: **"Поставить, *где нужно*, недостающие знаки препинания"**